# fread function not storing into buffer

Tags: c, file-io, buffer, file-handling

The fread function which I used doesn't appear to store contents in a buffer. Whenever I try to print the buffer, I get nothing.

How to solve this problem?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
   FILE* ptr1 = fopen("try.txt","r");
   int count = 0;
   while(fgetc(ptr1) != EOF)
   {
       count++;
   }
   char* buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*count);
   fread(buffer,sizeof(char),count, ptr1);
   printf("%s",buffer);
   fclose(ptr1);
   free(buffer);
}
```

Comment: 1. You need to check the return value of `fopen` to verify it succeeded. 2. After the `fgetc` loop the stream is at the end of the file. You need to [`rewind`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rewind) it back to the start of the file. 3. You need to `NUL` terminate the data that has been read as the `fread` is unlikely to produce a string.

Comment: Summary: read the documentation on the functions you're calling, and admire the return codes they provide, lest you fall into the pit of violating [Henry Spencer's 6th Commandment for C Programmers](https://www.seebs.net/c/10com.html).

Comment: Another nice example why error checking is quiet important. See: If the code doesn't store anything, it probably failed reading. So the 1st thing do to would be to RTFM on `fread()` trying to find out whether by any means this call could fail, and if it would, how it would communicate this back to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Use **rewind()** function after the **fgetc()** which sets the file position to the beginning of the file of the given stream. Like,

```
rewind(ptr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are counting characters in file, you are moving fpos pointer to EOF.
Then, you are trying to read counted number of characters, what is impossible without rewind to begin of file.
You have to use rewind.